# Find how many files/images can be shared by an app in Android

Tags: android, whatsapp

In my app, I am trying to find no. of files can be shared by an application. Like user can share only 10 images with WhatsApp. I want to know this before I could start sharing the image so that I could notify to user and avoid App launch call.

As of now, I can know only either App can handle single or multiple file share using intent action using [ACTION_SEND](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND) and [ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE) but don't know how many files can be shared.

Is there a way to figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to figure this out?

No.